# how to read material-table column headers array while dragging occurred using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-table

How to read material-table column headers array while dragging occurred using reactjs? I used onColumnDragged function but getting sourceIndex,destinationIndex only. I need to get all column headers order for passing to rest call to save the new order.

Answer (score 2):

There is one flexible way to get material-table column order while dragging.

```
function App() {
  const columns = [...];

  const data = [...];

  function handleColumnDrag() {
    let columnOrder = [];
    columns.forEach(column => {
      columnOrder.push({
        field: column.field,
        columnOrder: column.tableData.columnOrder
      });
    });
    console.log(columnOrder);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MaterialTable
        title="Tasks"
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        onColumnDragged={handleColumnDrag}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

You may have to change the format of *columnOrder* output based on your API call.

**DEMO:** [Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/crazy-noyce-xr8kj)

Answer (score 0):

You can grab a ref to the table itself using `tableRef` property and have access to table internals and column info/data among other things while dragging or at all times in general.

Comment: after using tableRef initially getting columns array, while dragging I'm not getting that array. could please explain with example..